# Auto Increment Column for Ordering

Tags: mysql

I have the following table and I just added the ord column because I need to ORDER BY ord all of my tasks selected for a user/group. I want them to always be returned in the order the user added the tasks. Otherwise the id column is useless since I already have a primary key.

I see a lot of answers saying why would you ever have an auto increment that isn't a primary key so I'm wondering if I'm somehow doing something wrong here. This seems like it would be commonly necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserTasks(
    ord int unsigned auto_increment,
    user_id int unsigned,
    group_id  smallint unsigned,
    task_id int unsigned,
    INDEX (ord),
    INDEX (user_id, group_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id, task_id)
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a sequence for ordering but a date or timestamp field with a default of "now". Sequences can be reset, or can be allocated seemingly out-of-order in the case of multiple transactions doing inserts at the same time.

Comment: What is the storage engine of the table ?

Comment: innodb though I could change it.